# How to define color for selected TextViews once in Android?

Tags: android, listview, textview, listviewitem, android-background

I have a `ListView` and created a xml file for `ListView` items.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/list_item_selector_back"
    android:minHeight="?attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <CheckedTextView
        android:id="@+id/list_item_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
        android:textColor="@color/list_item_selector_fore" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/list_item_author"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/list_item_selector_fore" />

        <!-- and many more TextView elements -->

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

`list_item_selector_fore.xml:`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@android:color/white" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:color="@android:color/white" android:state_activated="true" />
    <item android:color="@android:color/white" android:state_focused="true" />
    <item android:color="@android:color/black" />
</selector>
```

As you can see, I defined the background once in the root `LinearLayout`. But I had to set `android:textColor="@color/list_item_selector_fore"` for every `TextView`. 
I tried it with foreground, but nothing happened. How can I get this smarter?

HOW TO LOOK:
[two list view items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4LfVk.png)

Comment: You can programmatically find all children of your `LinearLayout` and text color to all of them.

Comment: Please post an image of the type of View you are looking.@EV221

Comment: what do you want to achieve ?

Comment: I don't want to say every single TextView how to look. I defined the background once in the first LinearLayout. But why can I not define the same for the text color? @user3486470: Yes, I did it, but it's not smart.

Comment: @CrazyAndroid: Ok. I did.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly you want to change the colour of the text inside a TextView. From your XML it seems you want it to be `onClick` therefore you can do this:

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
        textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                textView.setTextColor('set text color here');
            }
        });
```

---

EDIT:

If you have these items inside of a `ListView` I would suggest that the easiest way for you to achieve what you want is to set an `OnItemClickListener`and then change the `textColor` based on the `OnItemClick` event, which may look something like this;

```
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.rowItemTextView);
            textView.setTextColor('color goes here');
        }
    });
```

Hopefully this short snippet will guide you in the right direction to go.

Comment: Yes, but I have several TextViews. I don't want to get each of them manually. And I want to change the colors in xml. The advantage of this method is that the color state is saved on scrolling.

Comment: I see you've now edited to add a picture of what you mean, I'll edit my answer~

Comment: The problem is, that the color is disappearing when I scroll because of ListView's recycling. But if I use this style or XML stuff, the background color is still there if I scroll back.

Answer (score 0):

If you want do it for all TextView, the best way should be to subclass TextView

```
public class CustomeTextView extends TextView{

    public CustomeTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.setTextColor(R.color.white);  
    }
}
```